# Regex to match urls using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this regex which so far has been pretty good...

```
var r = /((ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?)/gi;
```

But if I have a string such as the following...

```
 '<div>http://www.a-random-site.com/page1-blah-blah</div>Another bit of text'
```

Then the bit that is matched would be...

```
http://www.a-random-site.com/page1-blah-blah</div>Another
```

How can I alter the regex to take into account that an angled bracked could terminate a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited **saram**'s `regex pattern` and tested it by **Expresso** and it worked with your sample :

```
(?:http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+(?:[\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is easy way to fix your regexp. I just use this code for url:

```
(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

Source [link](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=96)

[Working example](http://jsbin.com/amebiq/1/)